# Getting error Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react.js. And I am running the App.js but I am getting error as : -
×
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {blogCards}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Can anyone tell me why this error because I am new in react.js

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  const blogArr = [
    {
    id : 1,
    title: 'Blog Title 1',
    description : 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor'
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    title: 'Blog Title 2',
    description : 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor'
  },
  {
    id : 3,
    title: 'Blog Title 3',
    description : 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor'
  }]
  
  const blogCards = blogArr.map((item,pos) => {
    console.log(item)
    
    return (
      <div className="BlogCard" key={pos}>
        <h3>{item.title}</h3>
        <p>{item.description}</p>
      </div>
        
    );
  })

   return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        {blogCards}
      }
    </div>
  );

}



export default App;
```

Comment: You have two pairs of curly brackets, that's like passing an object as a child. Remove one pair: `<div className="App">{blogCards}</div>`

Comment: `.map()` returns new array, so your `blogCards` is an array. You need to use `.map()` in side return (render) statement

Answer (score 1):

As @zsolt-meszaros mentions in comments, the problem is with this code:

```js
    <div className="App">
      {
        {blogCards}
      }
    </div>
```

The outer braces on their own lines leave JSX mode and enter JavaScript mode.  In JavaScript, `{blogCards}` is equivalent to `{"blogCards": blogCards}`, i.e., make an object with one property with key `"blogCards"` and value equal to the `blogCards` variable.  Hence React gets an object and complains.

You just need to change your code to:

```js
    <div className="App">
      {blogCards}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
   <div className="App">
      {
        blogCards
      }
    </div>
```